# How can I control node values without input inside a group node?

Tags: node-editor, shaders, compositing-nodes, customization, drivers

I have created the node group, but I can't control the values inside.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Controlling ColorRamp nodes with Group Inputs](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16147/controlling-colorramp-nodes-with-group-inputs)

Comment: @RayMairlot I think there is another answer since Blender 2.82 which wasn't discussed in the related question, namely with the map range node which is effectively the same as a grayscale color ramp node with 2 stops, but with the obvious advantage of offering input fields.

Comment: @Gorgious Then an answer can be added on the other question. Just because there are new answers, it doesn't mean this isn't a duplicate question.

Comment: @RayMairlot Good point. Will do then.

Comment: @Gorigious The problem is that the topic I have linked has a question about the ColorRamp and that is why it is hard to find. I was looking for a general solution not connected to ColorRamp at all so this thread wasn't visible for me. I have found this thread by some forum where it was linked. So I decided that this is worth to make a post if it saves a few hours of searching.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue was discussed in [Controlling ColorRamp nodes with Group Inputs](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16147/controlling-colorramp-nodes-with-group-inputs) post but as Blender workflow get simplified and I wasn't able to find this post druging googling I decided to add another answer.

[image]

Right click on source and choose "copy as New Driver" then go to the target and "Paste Driver". You can use any group node silder as a Driver.

Comment: Just wanted to thank you for this tip :). It's so simple, yet somehow never crossed my mind.